# Mediatomb apt source on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, apt, source, mediatomb

I would like to install Mediatomb on my Debian Jessie. I keep seeing everywhere that people install it as simple as

```
sudo apt-get install mediatomb
```

but apparently I don't have mediatomb in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`. My current sources are:

```
deb http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/debian/debian/ stable main
deb-src http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/debian/debian/ stable main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/debian/debian/ stable-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/debian/debian/ stable-updates m$

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Could you please tell me what I have to add to get Mediatomb?

Answer (score 3):

Mediatomb wasn't included in Jessie because it suffers from a huge security bug which wasn't fixed in time for the release (and still isn't, see [the bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=580120) for details).

If you *really* want to install it, you could add `unstable` to your sources with the appropriate pinning (if that doesn't mean anything to you then you probably shouldn't), or you can manually download and install the three required packages from https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/mediatomb/download, https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/mediatomb-common/download (assuming you're using `amd64`) and https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/mediatomb-daemon/download.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't have a problem with security as it's my local home network. I'll download it and install it manually.